# When to use java function interface over methods?

Tags: java, function, methods, static

So I read that java was using static methods to imitate functions. As there is the function interface I am looking for a usecase where this is better to use.

So in case I want to reuse a method I can do it doing these:

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FClass fClass = new FClass();
        Integer i = fClass.apply(5);

        Integer i2 = SClass.apply(5);
    }

}

class FClass implements Function<Object, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer apply(Object o) {
        return (Integer) o;
    }
}

class SClass {

    public static Integer apply(Object o) {
        return (Integer) o;
    }
}
```

The static method below looks much more light weight to me while the Function interface looks like an overkill. Is this example to trivial to compare the `Function` interface to `static methods`?

Comment: The Function interface is almost never used this way. it's used as the type of a parameter of another method that wants to accept a lambda whose role is to transform an input into an output. Like for example `Stream.map(Function<T, R>)`, that you would call using, for example `stream.map(country -> conrty.getCapital())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java allows you to reach your goal in different ways, because there are different requirements, different contexts, different needs. That's why there is no approach that is *always* better than the others. Nobody forces you to use particular tools or particular design.

Do you have a simple logic with 100 - 200 lines of code? Then static method can be a good choice and `Function<Object, Integer>` is overkill. Do you plan to use functions as parameters in some logic and do you want to call them in some common way without distinguishing particular functions? Then the usage of `Function<Object, Integer>` can be better.